# Zooming into image in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, scrollviewer, windows-store-apps

I have a ScrollViewer with an Image Control in it. It displays a rather large image. I want my user to be able to zoom into the image using gestures. I therefore enabled the ZoomMode on the Scrollviewer. However the Scrollviewer automatically scrolls back to the left "edge" of the image whenever the user releases its finger, making effectively zooming in and out of the image impossible.

This is the Template i am using:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SingleItemTemplate">
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled">
        <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrlHighRes}">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable the horizontal scrolling as well (turned off by default)

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Auto"
```