# How to ZoomOut an image in MetroApp C#

Tags: image, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, semantic-zoom

I would like to zoomout the image from the flipView available in the GridProject of Win8 Metro App in C# XAML. I already have a scrollviewer but I would like to know if the user can simply double the image with mouse, so that only the image gets opened in a new page.

If so, it would be really great if you could suggest me how to proceed with it.

I followed this article [Zooming into image in Windows Store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229468/zooming-into-image-in-windows-store-apps)[SemanticZoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229468/zooming-into-image-in-windows-store-apps) but it doesn't help.

Thanks in Advance!